# Problems with updating WCF service reference in window phone app

Tags: wcf, windows-phone

I have a windows phone application that has WCF service . It works just fine when adding WCF service reference for the first time . But when I want to update the service reference It does not auto generate the code and I can not access the service any more. Any suggestion please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you delete the service reference completely and then re-add it does it work then?

Comment: No , It does not work then .

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the referenced service under the folder ServiceRefernce.
2. Select Configure Service Reference in the menu to access Service Reference Settings.
3. Above the list of assemblies, Select "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies:".
4. Check in the list "System.ServiceModel" and press OK.